# Problema com acentuação e caracteres especial deixar termo do autocomplete em negrito

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

Tenho esse script que faz um busca usando ao autocomplete do Jquery.

```js
$( function($) {
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {        
        var t = String(item.value).replace(
        new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
        "<strong>$&</strong>");
        return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + t + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };              
    
    $( "#p" ).autocomplete({
        source: "php/search_palavras.php?id_cidade=<?php echo $id_cidade; ?>",
        minLength: 2,
                        
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            // Set autocomplete element to display the label
            this.value = ui.item.label;
                    
            // Store value in hidden field
            $('#hidden_p').val(ui.item.id);

            // Prevent default behaviour
            return false;                   
        }
    });
                
    $( "#p" ).click(function() {
        $('#hidden_p').val(0);
        $('#p').val('');
    });         
});
```

Quase tudo está perfeito.
O único problema que estou tendo, não sei se é o PHP ou o Jquery, mas, se eu começar uma procura com "aco", vem as respostas:

Açougues

S**aco**lões Hortifrutigrangeiros

Centrais de Informações Turísticas

Atacado e Fabricação de S**aco**s plásticos

Tentei de todas as formas, mas não consigo destacar o "aço" ou "açõ" que estão com cedilha e acentos.
Seria possível destacar esses itens também?

Comment: Você esta apenas esta enviando o texto para seu servidor, que deve tratar os resultados que deve retornar, desta forma creio que seu problema não seja nem com PHP nem jQuery e sim banco. Ex.: `Mysql  collation utf8_general_ci`, se ele esta setado assim ele não faz distinção entre acentuadas ou não.

Comment: Na tabela que faço a pesquisa, o campo está com utf8_general_ci. Na página de busca do PHP, coloquei um mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8"); para não ter problemas com acentuação, mas mesmo assim, não destaca a acentuação.

Comment: Para ajudar: https://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não tenho certeza se é isso que você quer, mas tenho um solução. Use a função `htmlspecialchars()` na saída dos dados.

Comment: Fiz isso, mas continua a mesma coisa.